# Calculating percentile values in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, olap-cube, percentile

I am trying to calculate percentile (for example 90th percentile point of my measure) in a cube and I think I am almost there. The problem I am facing is, I am able to return the row number of the 90th percentile, but do not know how to get my measure.

```
With
Member [Measures].[cnt] as 
Count(NonEmpty(
-- dimensions to find percentile on (the same should be repeated again
[Calendar].[Hierarchy].members * 
[Region Dim].[Region].members * 
[Product Dim].[Product].members
,
-- add the measure to group
[Measures].[Profit]))

-- define percentile
Member [Measures].[Percentile] as 90

Member [Measures].[PercentileInt] as Int((([Measures].[cnt]) * [Measures].[Percentile]) / 100)

**-- this part finds the tuple from the set based on the index of the percentile point and I am using the item(index) to get the necessary info from tuple and I am unable to get the measure part 
Member [Measures].[PercentileLo] as
(
Order(
NonEmpty(
    [Calendar].[Hierarchy].members * 
    [Region Dim].[Region].members * 
    [Product Dim].[Product].members,
    [Measures].[Profit]),
    [Measures].[Profit].Value, BDESC)).Item([Measures].[PercentileInt]).Item(3)**

select
{
[Measures].[cnt],
[Measures].[Percentile],[Measures].[PercentileInt],
[Measures].[PercentileLo],
[Measures].[Profit]
}
on 0
from
[TestData]
```

I think there must a way to get measure of a tuple found through index of a set. Please help, let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should extract the tuple at position `[Measures].[PercentileInt]` from your set and add the measure to it to build a tuple of four elements. Then you want to return its value as the measure `PercentileLo`, i. e. define

```
Member [Measures].[PercentileLo] as
(
[Measures].[Profit],
Order(
NonEmpty(
    [Calendar].[Hierarchy].members * 
    [Region Dim].[Region].members * 
    [Product Dim].[Product].members,
    [Measures].[Profit]),
    [Measures].[Profit], BDESC)).Item([Measures].[PercentileInt])
)
```

The way you implemented it, you tried to extract the fourth (as `Item()` starts counting from zero) item from a tuple containing only three elements. Your ordered set only has three hierarchies.

Just another unrelated remark: I think you should avoid using complete hierarchies for `[Calendar].[Hierarchy].members`, `[Region Dim].[Region].members`, and `[Product Dim].[Product].members`. Your code looks like you are including all levels (including the all member) in the calculation. But I do not know the structure and names of your cube, hence I may be wrong with this.

Comment: like this? Member [Measures].[PercentileLo] as Order(
NonEmpty(
    [Calendar].[Hierarchy].members * 
    [Region Dim].[Region].members * 
    [Product Dim].[Product].members,
    [Measures].[Profit]),
    [Measures].[Profit].Value, BDESC)).Item([Measures].[PercentileInt])

Comment: @Prashant What do you mean by "does not work"? With just this sentence, I have no idea how to improve my answer. Do you get an error message? What does it say? Does it run but give a value that is not as you expect? If so, what did you expect and what is the returned value?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I am getting (null) value in PercentileLo column, which is unexpected. I was thinking, since I can get the dimensions with item(index), is it possible to use a select to get with where conditions to get the measure? and store it as a member. I am trying to build a calculated measure of percentiles.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method could be to find the median of the last 20% of the records in the table. I've used this combination of functions to find the 75th percentile. By dividing the record count by 5, you can use the TopCount function to return a set of tuples that make up 20% of the whole table sorted in descending order by your target measure. The median function should then land you at the correct 90th percentile value without having to find the record's coordinates. In my own use, I use the same measure for the last parameter in both the Median and TopCount functions.

Here's my code:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[90th Percentile] AS MEDIAN(
    TOPCOUNT(
        [set definition]
        ,Measures.[Fact Table Record Count] / 5
        ,Measures.[Value by which to sort the set so the first 20% of records are chosen]
    )
    ,Measures.[Value from which the median should be determined]
)
```

Based on what you've supplied in your problem definition, I would expect your code to look something like this:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[90th Percentile] AS MEDIAN(
    TOPCOUNT(
        {
           [Calendar].[Hierarchy].members * 
           [Region Dim].[Region].members * 
           [Product Dim].[Product].members
        }
        ,Measures.[Fact Table Record Count] / 5
        ,[Measures].[Profit]
    )
    ,[Measures].[Profit]
)
```